# Python renumbering algorithm for list indices

Tags: python

**EDITED:**

I have two lists of lists. Each list contains indices pointing to some other list/array (not shown). The index elements in each list are consecutive numbers. So the 1st list of lists has index elements 0-8 (unordered in sub-lists) and the 2nd list of lists has elements 9-17 (again unordered in sub-lists). This is the initial state.

As an example, I replace now some of the indices in the second list by elements of the first list (used to link some information between the lists). So I replace 9 by 2, 12 by 5 (2 times), and 15 by 8.
This is the intermediate state.

After replacing some elements, I want to renumber the remaining elements in the second list of lists (those that were not replaced by elements of the first list), so that there are no gaps in these list indices (not considering 2, 5, 8; these stay independent). This would be the final state.

```
10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17
```

should be:

```
9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
```

The smallest index in the second list must start at highest index of the first list +1 (in the example 8 is the highest index inthe first list, so we start with 9 in the second list when renumbering).

**Initial state:**

```
[[ 0,  1,  4,  3],      [[ 9, 10, 13, 12],
 [ 1,  2,  5,  4],       [10, 11, 14, 13],
 [ 3,  4,  7,  6],       [12, 13, 16, 15],
 [ 4,  5,  7,  8]]       [13, 14, 17, 16]]
```

**Intermediate state:**

```
[[ 0,  1,  4,  3],      [[ 2, 10, 13,  5],
 [ 1,  2,  5,  4],       [10, 11, 14, 13],
 [ 3,  4,  7,  6],       [ 5, 13, 16,  8],
 [ 4,  5,  7,  8]]       [13, 14, 17, 16]]
```

**End result:**

```
[[ 0,  1,  4,  3],      [[ 2, 10, 13,  5],
 [ 1,  2,  5,  4],       [ 9, 10, 12, 11],
 [ 3,  4,  7,  6],       [ 5, 11, 13,  8],
 [ 4,  5,  7,  8]]       [11, 12, 14, 13]]
```

In the example I replaced 4 items in the 2nd list of lists. Since the index 5 is used two times, I can reduce the index count in the 2nd list of lists by 3 (so the highest index is than 14 instead of 17).

I have coded this to work, but it is very unelegant. I search for help pointing me to a proper way to code this. Either by using set methods, itertools, graph algorithms, etc. I want to code this myself to learn the proposed method.

Andy

PS.: I found now why I couldn't paste the tables (now it is edited). I copied it from a PPT presentation and there seemed to be some control characters in the clipboard that automatically switched to the insert image mode (to paste code and all other icons were greyed out).

Comment: It made some Imgur images because you clicked on the "add image" button (or maybe you had an image in the clipboard and pasted it?). Just copy and paste the code as text and format it as code. See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) You seem to know how to include code from your previous posts here.

Comment: Please also include your current working code.

Comment: can you provide the code because what you have written made no sense. also why there is a 17 in the second matrix (is it a typo?). Can you explain why are you doing the operations so that it makes more sense.

Comment: Please provide some context too.

Comment: Your description of what you're trying to do isn't very clear. How do you select what numbers to replace and what their replacements should be (or is that irrelevant?) What do you mean by "makes consecutive indices obsolete"? What is the logic for renumbering? There are clearly gaps in the numbers in the second list, because you have `2, 5, 8...14` Including your code with a clear description of what it does and the _specific_ question you are asking us would help.

Comment: ok now it makes sense to me... it is pretty easy use a set to store the indices that you change. then use the length of the set to offset (renumber) the ones that are not in the set.

Comment: if the question wasnt closed I would have provided a code snippet for it. hope at least my comment would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I finally came up with this.

```
l1 = [[ 0,  1,  4,  3], [ 1,  2,  5,  4], [3,  4,  7,  6], [4,  5,  7,  8]]
l2 = [[9, 10, 13, 12], [10, 11, 14, 13], [12, 13, 16, 15], [13, 14, 17, 16]]
b1 = np.array(l1)
b2 = np.array(l2)
b2c = np.copy(b2)
s = [(9, 2), (12, 5), (15, 8)]
for c in s:
    b2c[b2c == c[0]] = c[1]
r = np.setdiff1d(np.unique(b2c), [c[1] for c in s])
f = [b1.max() + i + 1 for i in range(len(r))]
```

The remaining step is to put the values of f into b2c.

It now does exactly what I wanted. For the one liner with the numpy set methods I had a dirty unreadable loop before. Obviously I need to comment and re-format the code so that I can recall the meaning later. The compactness of the one liner has also kind of an unreadability in it, but it seems more concise to me compared to what I had before.